# Stata to Excel: Keeping the time variable correct

Tags: excel, stata, type-inference, date-conversion

I am trying to export a `.dta` file of mine from Stata to Excel. The file consists an important time variable. Though it shows fine in Stata, in the format of `%tm` (`2010m12` for example), when I export it to Excel it shows numbers. Tried to export it as csv, xls, xlsx, but doesn't seem to help. Example:

On Stata:

[image]

On Excel after exporting:

[image]

I also tried to play with the formats and types (it's `float` originally) but couldn't fix it. Didn't find any solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear to me why Stata exports %tm-formatted variables in this way. For example, 2010m2 is converted as 21916.000006956 when labeled, and as 601 when not.

However, this will export the %tm date as a string:

```
clear
set obs 10
gen time = _n+600
format time %tm

export excel using "time.xls", replace datestring("%tm")
```

Comment: This problem persists in Stata 14. Reported to StataCorp tech support.